# How do you access the RequestBody in a HandlerInterceptorAdapter?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I tried to pull the body out of `request.getReader()` but it was already read.

How can I get my hand on the requestbody within the interceptor?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the request body can only be read from the `Reader` once.  This is not specific to interceptors, but for all users of the Servlet API.

If you need to access the body a second time, then you need to store the data somewhere, such as in a request attribute (using `request.setAttribute()` and `request.getAttribute()`).

How and where you do this depends on your interceptor, and you told us nothing about your specific case.

Comment: As indicated in the question, it's a plain vanilla HandlerInterceptorAdapter. What else do you need to know?

Comment: @user366735: There's no such thing as "plain vanilla `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`". It's an empty base class with no behaviour. You need to subclass it to make it useful, and there are 3 different methods to implement, called at 3 different points in the request lifecycle. The answer depends entirely on how you've done this.

Comment: Plain vanilla means all I've done is implemented it with empty implementations. So for the sake of example, how do i get a handle on the requestBody within the preHandle method?

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception { //what now? }

Comment: @user366735: You're not making any sense.  If your interceptor methods are empty, it won't do anything, and `getReader()` is irrelevant.  Please alter your question and actually explain what you have, what's happens when you use it, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: the question makes perfect sense. it shouldn't matter what i want to do with it. the point is i want to do some processing on the request body within the interceptor methods. for the sake of example, say i want to log it in my interceptor. String reqBody = ?; LOGGER.log( reqBody );

Comment: clearly, spring had read it and stored it off somewhere. the question is where is it stored? some kind of requestcontextholder? it can't be that the only way to access it is in my controller. it's a simple question.

Comment: LOL, sounds like i've answered my own question. RequestContextHolder is a real thing!

Comment: doh! can't find it anywhere in that thing. surely the raw request body is stored somewhere...